# CSS hover effect not working when using ~, +, or >

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to change the hover selector I have now so that when I hover over the image or the "category card" div, the p text will come into view. I have tried a few things, but to no avail.

```
<div className="category-card" id="lessons-card">
    <div className="category-text" id="lessons">
        <h2>Lessons</h2>
        <p className="category-card-p lessons-p">Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <img src= "assets/img.jpeg" className="category-image" />
</div>
```

I have tried the following with ~, > and +

```
.category-card:hover ~ .category-card-p{
  transform: scale(1.2);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: It's just `class=`, not `className=`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/gf8pbm42/

Comment: @j08691 Sorry about that, it's React syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not quite hitting the meaning of those selectors:

- `~` means general sibling selector. The element must be at the same hierarchy level as the first selector and be somewhere *after* the first selector in the markup to qualify. `.category-card-p` is a descendant, so that won't work.
- `>` means direct descendant selector. The element must be an immediate child of the first selector to qualify. `.category-card-p` is not an immediate child, it is a grand-child, if you will, so that won't work.
- `+` means adjacent sibling selector. The element must be at the same hierarchy level and must be the `very next` element at that hierarchy level to qualify, so that won't work.

`.category-card:hover .category-card-p` would work, as would `.category-card:hover .category-text .category-card-p`. Even `.category-card-p` by itself would work, assuming you don't have another, more specific selector at play.

Also as j08691 mentioned, the HTML attribute for classes is `class=""`, not `className=""`. `.className=""` won't work, but a cursory check in an HTML validator would catch that right off the bat.